# Exiting STOP mode on STM32L100Rc

Tags: stm32, power-management, stm32ldiscovery

I am a new coder using the STM32L100RC discovery board. As such, my problem is quite simple I believe; I cannot exit Stop mode using an external trigger on the WakeUp Pin PA0. The code works as fallow: the LED on the PC9 pin light up, I enter STOP MODE and once I use the WakeUp command by pushing on the PA0 button, the LED turns off for a few seconds. Now I do know that using a a for loop isn't the right way to wait a few seconds, no need to point this out. I'd be very grateful if someone could explain what I am doing wrong. Here's what I've done so far:

```
void Button_Initialization (void)

{



RCC_APB2PeriphClockCmd(RCC_AHBPeriph_GPIOC, ENABLE);

RCC_APB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB1Periph_PWR,ENABLE);

RCC_AHBPeriphClockCmd(RCC_AHBPeriph_GPIOC, ENABLE);

RCC_AHBPeriphClockCmd(RCC_AHBPeriph_GPIOA, ENABLE);



// Configure PC9 as push-pull output

GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct;

GPIO_InitStruct.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_9;

GPIO_InitStruct.GPIO_Speed = GPIO_Speed_2MHz;

GPIO_InitStruct.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_OUT;

GPIO_Init(GPIOC, &GPIO_InitStruct);



GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStructA;

GPIO_InitStructA.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_0;

GPIO_InitStructA.GPIO_Speed = GPIO_Speed_2MHz;

GPIO_InitStructA.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_AF;

GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOA, GPIO_Pin_0, GPIO_AF_WKUP);

GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStructA);

PWR_WakeUpPinCmd(PWR_WakeUpPin_1, ENABLE);





GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStructButton;

// GPIO_InitStructButton.GPIO_Pin = ;

GPIO_InitStructButton.GPIO_Speed = GPIO_Speed_400KHz;

GPIO_InitStructButton.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_IN;

GPIO_InitStructButton.GPIO_PuPd = GPIO_PuPd_DOWN;

GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStructButton);



EXTI_InitTypeDef EXTI_InitStruct;

EXTI_InitStruct.EXTI_Line = EXTI_Line1;

EXTI_InitStruct.EXTI_LineCmd = ENABLE;

EXTI_InitStruct.EXTI_Mode = EXTI_Mode_Event;

EXTI_InitStruct.EXTI_Trigger = EXTI_Trigger_Rising;

EXTI_Init( &EXTI_InitStruct);

}



int main(void)

{

Button_Initialization();

while(1)

{

// Turn off LED on PC9

GPIO_SetBits(GPIOC, GPIO_Pin_9);





PWR_EnterSTOPMode(PWR_Regulator_ON, PWR_STOPEntry_WFE);


GPIO_ResetBits(GPIOC, GPIO_Pin_9);

for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)

{

}

}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your configuration you have no wakup source:

`PWR_WakeUpPinCmd(PWR_WakeUpPin_1, ENABLE);` is only usable if you want to wake the uC from standby, but not from stop mode. (see Reference manual chapter `5.3.8 Standby mode` and `5.4.2 PWR power control/status register (PWR_CSR)`)

With entering the stop mode like this `PWR_EnterSTOPMode(PWR_Regulator_ON, PWR_STOPEntry_WFE);` you need a qualified event to wake the uC. To achive this you simply have to configure the `PA0` as input (not the alternate wakeup function) with EXTI line event activated (which is `EXTI line 0`).

Also before entering stop mode you have to make sure, that all interrupt, EXTI line and RTC pending bits are cleared. Otherwise the enter stop mode is ignored.